# Python problem with circular reference:

Tags: python, circular-reference

I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Image (from image_blob.py)
```

please help me thanks :s

my code:

image.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from app.models.item import Item

class Image(Item):
    # imports
    from app.models.image_blob import ImageBlob
    #from app.models.user import User
    #from list_user import ListUser # is needed in order to have the references

    # references
    #uploaded_by_user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required = True)
    large_image = db.ReferenceProperty(ImageBlob, required = True)
    small_image = db.ReferenceProperty(ImageBlob, required = True)

    # image info
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = db.StringProperty(required = False)

    # metadata


    # relations
```

image_blob:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db


class ImageBlob(db.Model):
    from app.models.image import Image

    data = db.BlobProperty(required = True)
    image = db.ReferenceProperty(Image, required = True)
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016047/recursive-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to import from `image_blob.py` before the entirety of `image.py` is processed. At the time which the `from app.models.item import Item` occurs, `class Image` hasn't yet been defined, and thus can't yet be imported (the *entire* class definition must have been processed before the symbol is actually defined).

There's a simple solution to this: Don't define the `image` property on `ImageBlob`. AppEngine's models *automatically* define a backwards reference for you, so when you add the `ImageBlob` to the `Image`, it'll automatically define a property on the `ImageBlob` which references back to the set of `Image`s which reference it (which, in your current use case, should be of size 1).

Comment: The backwards reference is simply a query against the referencing property for itself.  I agree to not create refs in both directions.